# Dualboot Windows on existing LUKS full encrypted hdd

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, encryption, luks

So, I have a HDD with data on it, encrypted. I would like to install windows (8 or 10) on the same drive (allocate some space on it from that partition, it has 500+ GB free right now. I don't want to lose any data in this process and I don't want to lose my Ubuntu 16.04 installation that is on my main 250 GB SSD. Preferably Windows partition should be encrypted too (maybe unencrypted during load with grub). How should I do that?

lsblk output:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sda1   8:1    0 931,5G  0 part  
  └─luks-5d68bd0c-9fe0-45d5-b9eb-32c4216adaf3
       252:0    0 931,5G  0 crypt /media/nullifiedcat/b74a2320-5bcf-43ff-b4ee-44
sdb      8:16   0 232,9G  0 disk  
├─sdb1   8:17   0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0 232,4G  0 part  /
```

Comment: Windows doesn't support LUKS (pretty much nothing but Linux supports LUKS), so you can't do this directly. However, you should be able to do something similar by shrinking the LUKS container and creating a new partition for Windows, then turning on EFS (NTFS encryption) or, if you have an edition of Windows that allows for that, Bitlocker. Not posting this as an answer because I have no good suggestion on how exactly to accomplish that in practice.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling during installation process, won't windows corrupt my linux partitions and encryption?

Comment: It shouldn't, if you are careful. You may have to reinstall your Linux bootloader afterwards, but that should be about it. It's been a good while since I tried it, though. Of course, you should always make sure to have an up-to-date backup before making any such drastic changes to your system as installing an operating system always is, **before** doing anything. (Not that you shouldn't have up-to-date backups for other reasons as well...)

Comment: I don't have any HDD to store backups on.. I have a deja dup backup system running and it stores backups on that data 1TB hdd where I want to install windows